# Detecting variations in a data set

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba, analytics

I have a data set with this structure:

ContractNumber | MonthlyPayment | Duration | StartDate | EndDate

One contract number can occur many times as this data set is a consolidation of different reports with the same structure.

Now I want to filter / find the contract numbers in which MonthlyPayment and/or Duration and/or StartDate and/or EndDate **differ**.

Example (note that Contract Number is not a Primary key):

```
ContractNumber | MonthlyPayment | Duration | StartDate  | EndDate
           001 |            500 |       12 | 01.01.2015 | 31.12.2015
           001 |            500 |       12 | 01.01.2015 | 31.12.2015
           001 |            500 |       12 | 01.01.2015 | 31.12.2015
           002 |           1500 |       24 | 01.01.2014 | 31.12.2017
           002 |           1500 |       24 | 01.01.2014 | 31.12.2017
           002 |           1500 |       24 | 01.01.2014 | 31.12.2018
```

With this sample data set, I would need to retrieve 002 with a specific query. 001 is the the same and does not Change, but 002 changes over time.

Besides of writing a VBA script running over an Excel, I don't have any solid idea on how to solve this with SQL

My first idea would be a SQL Approach with grouping, where same values are grouped together, but not the different ones. I am currently experimenting on this one. My attempt is currently:

1.) Have the usual table

2.) Create a second table / query with this structure:

ContractNumber | AVG(MonthlyPayment) | AVG(Duration) | AVG(StartDate) | AVG(EndDate)

Which I created with Grouping.

E.G.

Table 1.)

```
ContractNumber | MonthlyPayment
             1 | 10
             1 | 10
             1 | 20
             2 | 300
             2 | 300
             2 | 300
```

Table 2.)

```
ContractNumber | AVG(MonthlyPayment)
             1 | 13.3
             2 | 300
```

3) Now I want to find the distinct contract number where - in this example only the MonthlyPayment - does not equal to the average (it should be the same - otherwise we have a variation which I need to find).

Do you have any idea how I could solve this? I would otherwise start writing a VBA or Python script. I have the data set in CSV, so for now I could also do it with MySQL, Power Bi or Excel.

I need to perform this Analysis once, so I would not Need a full approach, so the queries can be splitted into different steps.

Very appreciated! Thank you very much.

Comment: You're casting a very wide net there.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all contract numbers with differences, use:

```
select ContractNumber
from
(
select distinct ContractNumber,  MonthlyPayment , Duration , StartDate , EndDate
from MyTable
) x
group by ContractNumber
having count(*) >1
```